# PHP function not recognize different language

Tags: php, android, mysql, web-services, web-scraping

I have scrape data from telugu site now when I got English content from site I can get it without any issue but suppose content is of Telugu(Tamil language in India)

[Site url](http://www.123telugu.com/telugu/news/dhanalakshmi-talupu-tadite-in-post-production-stage.html)

It does not return correct string.

[Return string](http://prntscr.com/6sbqk5)

Code:

```
<?php

//
include "simple_html_dom.php";
// Get news from telugu site
$url = "http://www.123telugu.com/category/mnews";

$html = file_get_html($url);
$divs = $html->find('div.leading');
$result = array();
$status = FALSE;
$i = 0;
foreach ($divs as $d) {
    $status = TRUE;
    $title = $d->find('a', 0)->plaintext;
    $result[$i]['Title'] = $title;
    $link = $d->find('a', 0)->href;
    $result[$i]['Link'] = $link;
    $title = trim(mysql_real_escape_string($title));  // code for title
    $html = file_get_html($link);
    // code for image
    $image = '';
    foreach ($html->find('div.post-content') as $im) {
        $image = $im->find('img', 0)->src; // code for  image
    }
    $image = trim(str_replace('//', '', $image));
    $result[$i]['Image'] = $image;
    // code for content
    $content = '';
    foreach ($html->find('div.post-content p') as $co) {
        $content.= $co->plaintext;   // code for content
    }
    $result[$i]['Content'] = $content;
    $i++;
}

echo json_encode(array('Status' => $status, 'Data' => $result));
```

Comment: put the code you have used to scrap webpage.

Answer (score 0):

I have set content type utf-8 on top of the page also set collection "utf8_general_ci" of fields in phpmyadmin ([Url](http://prntscr.com/6tztfq)) now browser detect language([Url](http://prntscr.com/6tzujm)) but stile problem when this API called at android end.

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
```